# Get string after substring1 and before substring2

Tags: ruby

Let's say I'm having the following string:

```
Lorem Ipsum(tag1) is simply dummy text of(tag2) the printing and typesetting industry
```

And I want to get the substring between tag1 and tag2, hence

```
is simply dummy text of
```

How can I do that with Ruby?

Comment: `str[/(?<=\(tag1\)).*(?=\(tag2\))/].strip #=> "is simply dummy text of"`

Comment: ^^Use a lookbehind and a lookahead^^

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
str = "Lorem Ipsum(tag1) is simply dummy text of(tag2) the printing and typesetting industry"


str[/\(tag1\)(.*?)\(tag2\)/m, 1]
# => " is simply dummy text of"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `String#split`

```
str = "Lorem Ipsum(tag1) is simply dummy text of(tag2) the printing and typesetting industry"
str.split(/\(tag2\)|\(tag1\)/)[1]
#=>"is simply dummy text of"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use REGEX's [capturing technique](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Capturing). Let me explain:

```
> str = "Lorem Ipsum(tag1) is simply dummy text of(tag2) the printing and typesetting industry"

> a = str.match /\(tag1\)(.*)\(tag2\)/
=> #<MatchData "(tag1) is simply dummy text of(tag2)" 1:" is simply dummy text of">

> a[1]
=> " is simply dummy text of"
```

Here, I am escaping the parenthesis in your string using `\(` or `\)` because REGEX engine might get confused since it has special meaning.

Next, the `(.*)` refers to `capture` all the chars of length `any`. *Any* is implied by `*`(Asterisk).

In general it will match all the characters in between the two words you have as start & end point.

Answer (score 1):

A non-regex solution:

```
str = "Lorem Ipsum(tag1) is simply dummy text of(tag2) the printing industry"

str[str.index("(tag1)")+6..str.index("(tag2)")-1]
  #=> " is simply dummy text of"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lookbehind and lookahead and capture the text between:

```
> st='Lorem Ipsum(tag1) is simply dummy text of(tag2) the printing and typesetting industry'
> st[/(?<=tag\d\) ).*?(?=\(tag\d)/]
=> "is simply dummy text of"
```